# Disable client side validation in asp.net core at field level

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

In ASP.NET MVC i can disable client side validation at field level like

```
    @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BatchId, new { @class = "k-textbox" })
    @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(true); }
```

How do i do the same in `ASP.NET Core Mvc`?

I know i can do at application level in ConfigureService method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvc()
        .AddViewOptions(options =>
        {
            options.HtmlHelperOptions.ClientValidationEnabled = false;
        });

}
```

But i want to disable for a particular field

Comment: Hello, Did you try make a view model or just remove the validations from the field you have? Otherwise i would go to either this approach: [Docs: Model Disable validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#disable-validation) or i would try to see if the [jQuery Unobtrusive Validation](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive) has something for it.

Answer (score 2):

This works for Asp.Net Core 2.x, and I'm pretty sure it worked for 1.0, too:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Type" class="control-label"></label>       
    <input asp-for="Type" class="form-control" data-val="false"></label>       
    <span asp-validation-for="Type" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

—much cleaner than the earlier code.

Comment: !!! I just found myself trying to do this, thought "that's a good answer", and then realized it was mine (when I tried to upvote it)... I'm getting far too close to retirement!

Answer (score 1):

For Asp.Net Core, there is no built-in `Html.EnableClientValidation(false)`.

For a workaround, you could try specify `new { data_val = "false" }` in the view like

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Type" class="control-label" validatedisable="true"></label>       
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Type, new { data_val = "false" })
    <span asp-validation-for="Type" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```